# React Router- Link not directing properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following component...

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute  } from 'react-router'

class Bottom extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {link:"Don't have an account?"}
    }

    render(){

        return (
            <div>
            <div className="sub-login">
                <p>{this.state.link}<Link to="/register"> Register here</Link></p>
            </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Bottom;
```

As you can see I have a `<Link>` pointing to the page I want the user to go to if it is clicked.

This component is then bundled into another class called `<Register />`.

And then I have the following Routes...

```
class App extends React.Component {

    render(){

        return (
            <Router history={hashHistory}>
                <Route path='/' component={Index} >
                    <IndexRoute component={Register} />
                    <Route path='/register' component={Register} />
                </Route>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

When the `Link` is clicked, the url changes to `/register`, but the content of the page is still that of the home page, which is `<Index />` component.

Why won't it show the `<Register />` component? What must I change to render the register component when the link is clicked?

Comment: Why is the component property of <IndexRoute /> set to {Register}???  Shouldn't that be set to {Index}

Comment: @jamrizzi I changed it but it still has the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that all I had to do was add `{this.props.children}` to my Index Layout. So when the `Link` is clicked, the `Register` Layout will be loaded into my `Index` Layout.

The following code made it work...

```
 render(){

    return (
        <div>
        {this.props.children}  <-----
        <div className="sub-login">
            <p>{this.state.link}<Link to="/register"> Register here</Link></p>
        </div>
        </div>

    );
```